# regarding visual dsp ++

Tags: dsp-core

i've written a source code in visual dp ++ in c language. the platform is sharc processor adsp 21062.after the build is complete. while running the program it is displaying a message 
 `Instruction timed out with PC at: 0x20a5a` . what may be the error in my c code. can you please resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor is stalled. For example you are trying to read a peripheral register and there is no data available. This can have many different reasons so without further detail that's impossible to assess. First step would be to look at program memory at address 0x20a5a and see  what the processor was trying to do. Take a look at the disassembly window.